# ssh -T github.com results in ssh could not resolve hostname github

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I am trying to clone my public Git repository using Putty instead of Git Bash. I am doing this over ssh instead of Https(which is the requirement). The Linux machine which i am accessing through putty has IBM OS(Linux on z/os). I have created the rsa keys and added same on Github. While trying to clone my repository , i am getting error as 
**'ssh-rsa: /usr/lpp/Files/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 1: FSUM7351 not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.'** although the public key is present.

IBMUSER:/Z21S/usr/lpp/Files/.ssh: >ls
id_rsa      id_rsa.pub

When i am trying to issue command **ssh -T github.com**, i am getting error as **ssh could not resolve hostname github**

Please suggest.